# MS sql combine columns in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine multiple columns (varchar, but used to store boolean 'Y' or '') into a single column (list) with human readable text.

The Table layout is like this:

```
MEMBER_ID (int) | PROC (varchar) | 50K_12_MTHS (varchar) | 100K_12_MTHS (varchar)
1||||
2|Y|Y||
3|Y|Y|Y|
4|Y|||
```

For the output of the able sample I am trying to get:

```
1|
2|Proc, 50
3|Proc, 50, 100
4|Proc
```

I think the way to do this is with a Case (see below) but can't get it to work.

```
SELECT
MEMBER_ID,
Gorup =
Select(
CASE PROC
  WHEN 'Y'
  THEN 'Proc'
END  + ', ' +
CASE 50K_12_MTHS
  WHEN   'Y'
  THEN '50K'
END--  + ', ' +
CASE 100K_12_MTHS
  WHEN 'Y'
  THEN '100K'
END  + ', ' +)
from Members
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly...!

```
SELECT
MEMBER_ID,
CASE [PROC]
  WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Proc, '
  ELSE ''
END +
CASE [50K_12_MTHS]
  WHEN 'Y' THEN '50K,'
  ELSE ''
END +
CASE [100K_12_MTH]
  WHEN 'Y' THEN '100K, '
  ELSE ''
END  as [group]
from Members
```

Comment: @Rahul Yours will generate them at the start. Either way, removing them is trivial.

Comment: @podiluska..But the requirement is like that..need commas in the start..uyou can see it above

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
MEMBER_ID,
(CASE [PROC]  WHEN 'Y'
THEN 'Proc' ELSE ''
END +
CASE [50K_12_MTHS] WHEN 'Y'
THEN ', 50K' ELSE '' END   
+ CASE [100K_12_MTHS] WHEN 'Y'
THEN ', 100K' ELSE ''
END) as [GROUP]
from Members
```

Comment: @user1951570..did you get your expected result from the answer marked as correct...???

Comment: the first correct answer worked.  I did not notice the extra ','